# Within estimator and time fixed effects

Tags: linear-model, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

If I data on a variable Y for 3 firms (A,B,C) over 3 years (1,2,3), then the linear firm fixed-effects model with year dummies (i.e. time fixed effects) **without covariate** would be:

$Y_{it}=\alpha + \beta_2Firm_B+ \beta_3Firm_C+ \beta_5Year_2+ \beta_6Year_3+\epsilon $

where $Firm_B$, $Firm_C$, $Year_2$ and $Year_3$ are dummies. $Firm_A$ and $Year_1$ are dropped to avoid multicollinearity.

In this case, $\beta_5$ is the differential effect of $Year_2$ for $Firms_A$ relative to the omitted/base category: $Firm_A$ in $Year_1$

**Now, what would be the interpretation of this same coefficient on $Year_2$ if I add a continuous regressor $X_{it}$ in the regression**. Would it still represent the impact of $Year_2$ on $Firms_A$ only (holding $X$ constant)?

Comment: There is no multicollinearity if you drop the intercept.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but this is not my main concern. As I mentioned, I want to understand the interpretation of the coefficient on $Year_2$.